# Distribution of number of values less than cutoff within symmetric Dirichlet

Tags: monte-carlo, cumulative-distribution-function, dirichlet-distribution

Assume have a symmetric Dirichlet distribution with $a_1= \dots =a_k = a$

$
(X_1, \ldots, X_K)\sim\operatorname{Dir}(a)
$

I am trying to determine the distribution of the number of values less than some cut-off. That is, for $\Pr(N=n|c,a,k)$  $n$ values were less than $c$ while $k-n$ were greater than $c$

Example for two values:

$\Pr(N=2|c,a,3) = \Pr(X_1<c, X_2<c, X_3>c)
 + \Pr(X_1<c, X_2>c, X_3<c)
+ \Pr(X_1>c, X_2<c, X_3<c)
$
*(which being symmetric Dirichlet should simplify, but wanted to show individually all combinations as an example)*

Did 1E7 simulations for $(c=.1, a=.5, k=3)$ and got:

```
       n     count
       0     2,492,498
       1     5,527,905
       2     1,979,597
       3           0
```

So out 1E7 simulation, around 25% of the cases had zero values that were less than .10

Is there a general formula for the distribution of $N$ as a function $c$? (given $a$ and $k$)

Or, an approximation for small c? ($c\ll\frac{1}{k}$)